# Is there a method like JavaScript's substr in Rust?

Tags: string, substring, rust

I looked at the Rust [docs for `String`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html) but I can't find a way to extract a substring.

Is there a method like JavaScript's [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) in Rust? If not, how would you implement it?

```
str.substr(start[, length])
```

The closest is probably `slice_unchecked` but it uses byte offsets instead of character indexes and is marked `unsafe`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75186999/14247462

Answer (score 80, accepted):

For characters, you can use `s.chars().skip(pos).take(len)`:

```
fn main() {
    let s = "Hello, world!";
    let ss: String = s.chars().skip(7).take(5).collect();
    println!("{}", ss);
}
```

Beware of the definition of Unicode characters though.

For bytes, you can use the slice syntax:

```
fn main() {
    let s = b"Hello, world!";
    let ss = &s[7..12];
    println!("{:?}", ss);
}
```

Comment: Didn't see `chars()`, thanks! Would it also be possible to map the char index to a byte offset and create a slice from that?

Comment: @laktak, you can use `str::char_indices` for that. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.char_indices

Comment: In the second example I think you meant `b"Hello, world!"` ?

Answer (score 17):

You can use the [`as_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html#method.as_str) method on the [`Chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html) iterator to get back a `&str` slice after you have stepped on the iterator. So to skip the first `start` chars, you can call

```
let s = "Some text to slice into";
let mut iter = s.chars();
iter.by_ref().nth(start); // eat up start values
let slice = iter.as_str(); // get back a slice of the rest of the iterator
```

Now if you also want to limit the length, you first need to figure out the byte-position of the `length` character:

```
let end_pos = slice.char_indices().nth(length).map(|(n, _)| n).unwrap_or(0);
let substr = &slice[..end_pos];
```

This might feel a little roundabout, but Rust is not hiding anything from you that might take up CPU cycles. That said, I wonder why there's no crate yet that offers a `substr` method.

Comment: "not hiding anything from you that might take up CPU cycles" - can you explain why substr might be more expensive than any of the trim functions it has?

Comment: Well... the trim functions are expected to get rid of all whitespace they encounter. This is a O(n) operation by definition. But using a `substr` method the user might assume that it is O(1), because they are entering indices.

Comment: `but Rust is not hiding anything from you that might take up CPU cycles.` This is not true since `Vec::insert` exists

Answer (score 7):

This code performs both substring-ing and string-slicing, without panicking nor allocating:

```
use std::ops::{Bound, RangeBounds};

trait StringUtils {
    fn substring(&self, start: usize, len: usize) -> &str;
    fn slice(&self, range: impl RangeBounds<usize>) -> &str;
}

impl StringUtils for str {
    fn substring(&self, start: usize, len: usize) -> &str {
        let mut char_pos = 0;
        let mut byte_start = 0;
        let mut it = self.chars();
        loop {
            if char_pos == start { break; }
            if let Some(c) = it.next() {
                char_pos += 1;
                byte_start += c.len_utf8();
            }
            else { break; }
        }
        char_pos = 0;
        let mut byte_end = byte_start;
        loop {
            if char_pos == len { break; }
            if let Some(c) = it.next() {
                char_pos += 1;
                byte_end += c.len_utf8();
            }
            else { break; }
        }
        &self[byte_start..byte_end]
    }
    fn slice(&self, range: impl RangeBounds<usize>) -> &str {
        let start = match range.start_bound() {
            Bound::Included(bound) | Bound::Excluded(bound) => *bound,
            Bound::Unbounded => 0,
        };
        let len = match range.end_bound() {
            Bound::Included(bound) => *bound + 1,
            Bound::Excluded(bound) => *bound,
            Bound::Unbounded => self.len(),
        } - start;
        self.substring(start, len)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = "abcdèfghij";
    // All three statements should print:
    // "abcdè, abcdèfghij, dèfgh, dèfghij."
    println!("{}, {}, {}, {}.",
        s.substring(0, 5),
        s.substring(0, 50),
        s.substring(3, 5),
        s.substring(3, 50));
    println!("{}, {}, {}, {}.",
        s.slice(..5),
        s.slice(..50),
        s.slice(3..8),
        s.slice(3..));
    println!("{}, {}, {}, {}.",
        s.slice(..=4),
        s.slice(..=49),
        s.slice(3..=7),
        s.slice(3..));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For `my_string.substring(start, len)`-like syntax, you can write a custom trait:

```
trait StringUtils {
    fn substring(&self, start: usize, len: usize) -> Self;
}

impl StringUtils for String {
    fn substring(&self, start: usize, len: usize) -> Self {
        self.chars().skip(start).take(len).collect()
    }
}

// Usage:
fn main() {
    let phrase: String = "this is a string".to_string();
    println!("{}", phrase.substring(5, 8)); // prints "is a str"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by *oli_obk* does not handle correctly the last index of the slice.

Here `substr` implements rust-styled slicing while taking corner cases into account.

```
pub fn substr(s: &str, begin: usize, end: Option<usize>) -> Option<&str> {
    use std::iter::once;
    let mut itr = s.char_indices().map(|(n, _)| n).chain(once(s.len()));
    let begin_byte = itr.nth(begin)?;
    let end_byte = match end {
        Some(end) if begin >= end => begin_byte,
        Some(end) => itr.nth(end-begin-1)?,
        None => s.len(),
    };
    Some(&s[begin_byte..end_byte])
}

// Tests
let s = "abc";
assert_eq!(Some("bc"),  substr(s, 1, Some(3)));
assert_eq!(Some("c"), substr(s, 2, Some(4)));
assert_eq!(Some("c"), substr(s, 2, None));
assert_eq!(Some(""),    substr(s, 2, Some(2)));
assert_eq!(Some(""),    substr(s, 2, Some(1)));
assert_eq!(None,        substr(s, 2, Some(5)));
```

Note that this does not still handle unicode *grapheme clusters*. For example, `"y̆es"` contains 4 unicode characters but 3 grapheme clusters. This can be solved with crate [unicode-segmentation](https://crates.io/crates/unicode-segmentation) by replacing iterator `.char_indices()`  with `.grapheme_indices()`.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing about the various syntaxes of the slice type might be beneficial for some of the readers.

- Reference to a part of a string
  `&s[6..11]`
- If you start at index 0, you can omit the value
  `&s[0..1]` ^= `&s[..1]`
- Equivalent if your substring contains the last byte of the string
  `&s[3..s.len()]` ^= `&s[3..]`
- This also applies when the slice encompasses the entire string
  `&s[..]`
- You can also use the range inclusive operator to include the last value
  `&s[..=1]`

Link to docs: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html

Answer (score -1):

I'm not very experienced in Rust but I gave it a try. If someone could correct my answer please don't hesitate.

```rust
fn substring(string:String, start:u32, end:u32) -> String {
    let mut substr = String::new();
    let mut i = start;
    while i < end + 1 {
        substr.push_str(&*(string.chars().nth(i as usize).unwrap().to_string()));
        i += 1;
    }
    return substr;
}
```

Here is a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3ce3a45400fbd79f9c456c6f8873c9f1)

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find the exact `substr` implementation that I'm familiar with from other programming languages like: JavaScript, Dart, and etc.

Here is possible implementation of method `substr` to `&str` and `String`

Let's define a trait for making able to implement functions to default types, (like `extensions` in Dart).

```rust
trait Substr {
    fn substr(&self, start: usize, end: usize) -> String; 
}
```

Then implement this trait for `&str`

```rust
impl<'a> Substr for &'a str {
  fn substr(&self, start: usize, end: usize) -> String {
      if start > end || start == end {
          return String::new();
      }
      
      self.chars().skip(start).take(end - start).collect()
  }
}
```

Try:

```rust
fn main() {
    let string = "Hello, world!";
    let substring = string.substr(0, 4);
    println!("{}", substring); // Hell
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also use `.to_string()[ <range> ]`.

This example takes an immutable slice of the original string, then mutates that string to demonstrate the original slice is preserved.

```rust
let mut s: String = "Hello, world!".to_string();

let substring: &str = &s.to_string()[..6];

s.replace_range(..6, "Goodbye,");

println!("{}   {} universe!", s, substring);

//    Goodbye, world!   Hello, universe!
```

Comment: This is not like JavaScript: `"ウィキペディアへようこそ".substr(1, 3)` vs `&"ウィキペディアへようこそ"[1..3]`. One "works", the other doesn't.

Comment: @Shepmaster Correct. This does not work for all characters. The `skip.take.collect` method is ideal.