# How does skip works in Rust?

Tags: rust

I've just seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37158376/7445826) on how to search for a substring in a given Rust string. The code is something along these lines:

```
let s = "Hello, world!";
let ss: String = s.chars().skip(7).take(5).collect();
```

But I am now curious to know how that `skip` really works. Does it really iterate over the first 7 elements of the iterator before starts yielding? Or it does some trickery behind the scenes?

Comment: Why wouldn't it do exactly what you think it does?

Comment: Since this is a string, I can imagine the implementation really just does the equivalent of adding 7 to a pointer and doing a bounds check.

Comment: @tadman It can't add `7` because `String`s are utf8 so characters are not a fixed number of bytes.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I'm giving a huge simplification here, but it's likely just skipping ahead pointer-wise.

Comment: I mean with enough simplification everything is pointers pretty much :P All I wanted to point out is that it felt like your comment was misleading because 7 bytes is not 7 characters. Or not misleading but at least potentially adding confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [`Skip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/adapters/skip.rs.html#37) implementation, you can see it relies on [`Iterator::nth`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.nth) internally.

[`Chars` implementation of iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/str/iter.rs.html#36-72) uses the default `nth` implementation, that call next in a loop.

[`slice::Iter` implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice/iter/macros.rs.html#166-186) offers a specialized implementation of `nth`, basically just bumping the internal cursor.

As @tadman mentioned, you can't just jump to a char position in a UTF-8 string, so the default implementation is probably the right only.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from the [Rust documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip):

> Creates an iterator that skips the first n elements.
> After they have been consumed, the rest of the elements are yielded.

Basic example:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3];

let mut iter = a.iter().skip(2);

assert_eq!(iter.next(), Some(&3));
assert_eq!(iter.next(), None);
```